# Quotient rule in multivariables wrong?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I noticed a weird behaviour of the quotient rule in multidimensions.

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x):=\sqrt{g(x)+a}$ where $g$ is a non-negative function and $a$ positive.

Then

$$D^2 f(x) = D \left(\frac{Dg(x)}{2 f(x)} \right)$$

and now I wanted to apply the quotient rule such that

$$= \frac{D^2 g(x) f(x)- Dg(x) Df(x)}{(2f(x))^2} = \frac{D^2 g(x) f(x)- Dg(x) \frac{Dg(x)}{2f(x)}}{(2f(x))^2}.$$

Now the problem is that the first term in the nominator is a Hessian matrix(!), but in the second term we have two row vectors, so the product is not defined.

Therefore, I guess it has to be 
$$= \frac{D^2 g(x) 2f(x)- Dg(x)^T 2Df(x)}{(2f(x))^2} = \frac{D^2 g(x) 2f(x)- Dg(x)^T \frac{Dg(x)}{f(x)}}{(2f(x))^2}.$$

But I don't see where I made the mistake, so that the transpose appears. Or is this calculation completely wrong?

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Comment: Perhaps the second term of the second term should be transposed so that you may get an outer product (tensor product) and you'll have 2 matrices.

Comment: Note that you should either add a factor of $2$ to each term in the numerator, or take the $2$ out of the square in the denominator.

Comment: @grdgfgr notice that $Dg$ is a row vector, so transposing the first one actually gives me the matrix.

Comment: Which is potentially what you want.

Comment: @grdgfgr so I don't understand why you want to transpose the second term, that would mean that the first one is a row vector and the second one a column vector, so you end up with a number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem stems from the fact that you consider the Hessian as a matrix with rows and columns, whereas in reality both index variables have the same tensorial status: The Hessian is not the matrix of a linear map ${\Bbb R}^n\to{\Bbb R}^n$, but the matrix of a quadratic form on ${\Bbb R}^n$.

I shall subsume the $a$ into $g$, so that we simply have $$f:=\sqrt{\mathstrut g}:\quad{\Bbb R}^n\to{\Bbb R}_{\geq0}\ .$$ Let's look at the partial derivatives:
$$f_{.i}:={\partial f\over\partial x_i}={g_{.i}\over 2f}\ ,$$
and then $$f_{.ik}={\partial\over\partial x_k}\left({g_{.i}\over 2f}\right)={g_{.ik}\over2f}-{g_{.i}f_{.k}\over 2f^2}={g_{.ik}\over2f}-{g_{.i}g_{.k}\over 4f^3}\ .\tag{1}$$
The $f_{.ik}$ are the elements of the Hessian of $f$, and are obviously symmetric in the index variables $i$ and $k$. Given that $d^2f(X)=\sum_{i,k}f_{.ik}\>X_i X_k$ one may write $(1)$ in a coordinate free way as follows:
$$d^2f(X)={1\over 2f}d^2g(X)-{1\over4f^3} \left(dg(X)\right)^2\ .$$